# Wrong hour to wake up with rtcwake

Tags: 14.04, suspend, wakeup

I want my Ubuntu 14.04 to shutdown, then wake up 06:00 AM with Windows. To achieve that task, I edited the grub so the default option is Windows, and created this script:

```
sudo su << EOF
    rtcwake -m mem -t `date +%s -d"tomorrow 06:00"`
    shutdown -r now
EOF
```

But instead of waking up at 06:00 AM, I noticed my computer waked up at 02:00 AM.

Note: The BIOS time is sync with OS time.

What am I doing wrong with the time?
Is there any better option to achieve what I want?

Comment: check bios time

Comment: BIOS date and time is sync with OS date and time,

Comment: The %s is UTC, so adjust for your timezone.